# java.lang.NullPointerException when trying to call SDN from aws lambda handler function

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, aws-lambda

I have a handler function inside which I'm calling my spring data repository interface. The code works fine in my main method or from the jar, but throws NullPointerException when I upload the jar in s3 and call from aws lambda where I call the repository method. below is my lambda handler method;

```
public class LambdaRestFunction implements RequestHandler<String, Object> {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(String uname, Context context) {
        String time = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        context.getLogger().log("Lambda call started: " + time);

        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
        context.getLogger().log("Array initialized.");
        **users = userRepository.findByName(uname);** // <-- NullPointerException thrown here
        context.getLogger().log("Method call over..");
        ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        String json = "[]";
        try {
            json = ow.writeValueAsString(users);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            context.getLogger().log("Error from application : " + e.getMessage());
        }

        context.getLogger().log("Lambda function completed: " + time);
        return json;
    }

}
```

My repository interface is;

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "user", path = "user")
public interface UserRepository extends GraphRepository<User> { 
    @Query("MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.id =({id}) RETURN u")
    User findUser(@Param("id") Long id);    
}
```

and domain class is;

```
@NodeEntity
public class User {

    @GraphId Long id;
    private String name;
    private String dob;
    private String cc;

    public User(String name, String dob, String cc) {
        this.name = name;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.cc = cc;
    }

    public User() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
...
```

Please find below the trace log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.test.lambda.LambdaRestFunction.handleRequest(LambdaRestFunction.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$PojoMethodRequestHandler.handleRequest(EventHandlerLoader.java:439)
at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$PojoHandlerAsStreamHandler.handleRequest(EventHandlerLoader.java:370)
at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$2.call(EventHandlerLoader.java:972)
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:235)
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.<clinit>(AWSLambda.java:60)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry.main(LambdaRTEntry.java:94)
```

I would be really grateful if anyone could help me find the cause of the exception. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please, post the complete stacktrace and highlight the provided line number in your code

Comment: The error is thrown in the handleRequest()  function where userRepository.findByName(uname); is called. Thanks.

Comment: Then `userRepository` might be null or something inside the `findByName` method is null. Again, post the complete stacktrace and highlight the line where the error occurs. Without the stacktrace we cannot tell you where the issue is.

Comment: Can you highlight line 36 of `LambdaRestFunction` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambda does not support annotations, so @Autowired will not have the desired effect.

At https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-programming-model-req-resp.html , see the note under "Handler Input/Output: POJO Type".

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply @Jeff Learman. You are correct, that seems to be the issue. I don't know how I overlooked that section in the guide. I was able to fix the problem. Appreciate your help!

Comment: so basically how to take advanatge of both Spring Boot and AWS Lambda ?

Comment: @KNU - that might be a good question post, though it'd take some work to set up an example and try some solutions as an example.  I no longer work at AWS and only use Lambda for personal projects, so I can't help you further.  Welcome to SO, btw.

Comment: If you do post a question, feel free to link to it in a comment here so I can see it and help you make sure it's a good question post.